# Why is it so difficult to prove the irrationality of the zeta function for $N$?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, irrational-numbers, fake-proofs, zeta-functions

I know that no one has yet been able to prove that the zeta function is irrational at every point $N$.
but my question is why is it so difficult to prove the irrationality of the zeta function for $N$?

For example i find a good argument why the zeta function should be irrational (not a proof i know):

Assume that the zeta function at every point is rational
you could write it like that

$$\frac{p_n}{q_n}= \zeta(n)= 1+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{5^n}+\ldots$$

Now divide the sum on the left into $2$ sums with the proviso that one side shares a factor with $q_n$ and the other does not.

\begin{align*}\frac{p_n}{q_n} &= (\text{not Factor with }q_n) + \left[\frac{1}{q_n^n}+\frac{1}{(2q_n)^n}+\frac{1}{(3q_n)^n}+\frac{1}{(4q_n)^n}+\ldots\right] \\
&= (\text{not Factor with }q_n) + \frac{1}{q_n^n}\cdot\left[1+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\frac{1}{4^n}+\frac{1}{5^n}+\ldots\right] \\
&= (\text{not Factor with }q_n)+ \frac{1}{q_n^n}\cdot\zeta(n) \\
&= (\text{not Factor with }q_n) + \frac{p_n}{q_n^{n+1}}
\end{align*}

Then reshaping creates the requirement that both sides have a factor with $q_n$, which is a contradiction!

What are your considerations for this "proof"? And does anyone have an idea how to fully prove it with this method?

Comment: "I know that no one has yet been able to prove that the zeta function is irrational at every point N. but my quastion is whyis it so difficult to prove the irrationality of the zeta function for N?" -- Who says they are all irrational? Notably, $\zeta(s)=0$ for $s$ a negative even integer. I'm also reasonably sure you can't have a nonconstant continuous function take on exclusively irrational values per density and the IVT. Besides that, proving irrationality can often be a nontrivial task regardless, depending on the constant.

Comment: Please have a look at [Zudilin's paper](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=387&option_lang=eng) to learn about the difficulties to prove irrationality. His ideas could give a proof that $\zeta(2n+1)$ is irrational. See also other posts about this paper, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523183/an-argument-in-paper-of-wadim-zudilin-irrationality-of-values-of-riemann-zeta-f).

Comment: A so simple approach only works in special cases, for example for the constant $e$. For $\pi$ , we already need more complicated approaches. Irrationality proofs are usually extremely difficult, so don't we know for each of the numbers $\ e+\pi\ $, $\ e\cdot \pi\ $ , $\gamma$ whether it is an irrational number.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a theorem which knew which properties a polynomial or better any diffrential function f must had so that sum(1/f(n),n,1,infitiy) = irrational

Answer (score 1):

It's always hard to say when an idea that *hasn't* produced a proof *could* lie on the road to a proof. That said, in my mind, your argument doesn't get us any closer.

The key issue: the term you call "(not Factor with $q_n$)". You don't give any suggestion of how we can prove anything about it. Specifically, how do we know it isn't the rational number $\frac{p_n}{q_n}-\frac{p_n}{q_n^{n+1}}$? Proving that looks just as hard as proving that $\zeta(n)$ is irrational.